# cvCalcEigenObjects and cvEigenDecomposite in Python

Tags: python, image-processing, opencv

I'm trying to implement a face based authentication system in python using [this](http://www.cognotics.com/opencv/servo_2007_series/part_5/page_3.html) as a base.

In the original cpp code, `cvCalcEigenObjects` and `cvEigenDecomposite` are used. But I can't find python equivalents for these. I've searched online for possible modules to import but couldn't find a lead (except to implement them using numpy).

I would really appreciate any pointers on either an equivalent function or on how to implement these using numpy. I'm not going to ask for coding but I think it would help others in the future.

Answer (score 3):

There is article written by Philip Wagner on two ways of face recognition, one of which is using eigen faces. He also contributed this to OpenCV 2.4 and now available in samples.

In the article, he has generated eigen faces with the help of numpy . You can check it and implement yourself.

http://www.bytefish.de/pdf/facerec_python.pdf

Check his github account for python codes : https://github.com/bytefish/facerecognition_guide